# Rotate UIView for more than 360 degress with decreasing speed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I have a UIView and I want to rotate it around its center point for N number of rotations within a given T time duration.**And the speed of the rotation should be decrease gradually. (like a rotation wheel)**.  I have below code and its not working properly.

```
   float T = 5; // 5 seconds
   float rotations = 10;
   //_containerView is the view to be rotate

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:T];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformRotate(_containerView.transform, (2*M_PI*rotations + 0));
    _containerView.transform = t;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: "Not working properly"… what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define StartAnimation(duration) [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];    \
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];       \
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];   \
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0]

#define StopAnimation [UIView commitAnimations]
```

Define these macros and use

```
StartAnimation(<time>)
//your code
StopAnimation
```

Comment: I think this should be a comment. not an answer.

Comment: This is not the answer by anyway. :P

Comment: Did something similar by dooing 360 in one go and executing n times and increasing time each time did it in showing chess pecies move used static int to increase time

Comment: Why would you use macros like that? The block based API offers the same (and more) functionality but is cleaner and easier to understand?

Comment: Found it convenient in an social app it had animation for every event

Comment: dear dwn voters just becoz you dnt fid things usefull dsnt mean they are use less :P